# Centering div element inside html header tag

Tags: css, html, centering

I am trying to center my div element with class name `toolbar` and i have tried using the `inline-block` property on the div element and `text-align: center` on the header tag with no luck.

Here is the html

```
<header>
   <div class="toolbar">
   </div>
<header>
```

and the corresponding css stylings

```
 header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 51px !important;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    z-index:100;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.toolbar {
    background: #fff;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
    top: 0;
    width: 910px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Having no luck centering the inner div element, with the current settings it moves it all the way to the right and if i remove the display on the div, it brings it to the left

Comment: `.toolbar{ left:50%; margin-left:-455px; ...etc }`

Comment: Which browsers are you experiencing this in? Is this what you are experiencing: http://jsfiddle.net/LQfJY/ ?

Comment: All browsers but with Shmiddty's solution all is well now. Thanks gentlemen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove `position: fixed` and `top: 0` as it is not needed
....

and change to `display:block` from the **.toolbar** class.

Here's a quick sample:

http://jsfiddle.net/Riskbreaker/QePqL/

if you don't want to remove `position: fixed` then:

http://jsfiddle.net/QePqL/1/

Comment: I need the position fixed as the tool bar has some javascript that allows user to scroll back to the top so i need the tool bar to be there always. Otherwise your solution works.

Comment: I see **sadaf** added the answer for you aswell as me :)

http://jsfiddle.net/Riskbreaker/Zunhz/