# CSS Div not centering

Tags: css, margin

My intention is to center a header `<div>`, but i'm not able to do it.

```
header {
   height: 54px;
   margin:0px auto;
   width: 1150px;
   background: #13171B;
   position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   z-index: 990;
   margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

Please help me.

Comment: Please check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14062991/centering-div-element-inside-html-header-tag

Answer (score 1):

`margin: 0 auto` can center elements in `static` or `relative` position only. Since your div is in `fixed` position you may try with

```
header {
   position: fixed;
   height: 54px;
   width: 1150px;
   ...
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: -575px; /* 1150px/2 */ 
   top: 0;
}
```

if you don't know in advance the `width`, a better solution involves `css3` transformations, e.g.

```
header {
   position: fixed;
   height: 54px;
   ...
   left: 50%;
   transform: translateX(-50%);
   top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My go to solution for centering is thus;

```
.parent {
 position: relative;
}
.toCenter {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
 -moz-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
 -o-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
 -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
 transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

This positions the .toCenter element vertically and horizontally centered to it's .parent.

If you needed to position only horizontally, each 'translate(-50%-50%)' in the element's style would become 'translateX(-50%)'. Similarly, if vertical alignment was required, you could use 'translateY(-50%)' instead.

The important thing here is that there is a limit to browser support. Essentially everything except IE will work fine, with anything from IE9 backwards causing issues. There are poly fills and hacks to get things to work however, and they're usually neater than having to create additionally classes or style sheets just for one piece of functionality.

Comment: uhm I think you're missing left: 50% & top: 50%, using what you posted above, would just bring that element to -50% left and top

Comment: Good spot, thanks! I had a second solution in head that had 0's instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the `fixed` position. Add/change the properties below:

```
left: 50%;
-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
-moz-transform: translateX(-50%);
transform: translateX(-50%);
```